# How to tell 'appengine-maven-plugin' not to use oauth2 for deploys to appengine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, appengine-maven-plugin

We're switching from the unofficial 'kidleit' maven plugin to use the official "appengine-maven-plugin" http://code.google.com/p/appengine-maven-plugin/

Our application is not new, but when deploying now, we get the error:

```
404 Not Found This application does not exist (app_id=u'appname')
```

Running on the command line and in eclipse, turns out the same message pops up when telling `appcfg.sh` to use `--oauth2` for authentication, which turns out to be the default for the 'appengine-maven-plugin'.

Is there a way to tell the official maven plugin to not use Oauth2 authentication?

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out by reading the source.  I can specify the `oauth2` property to be `false` in the pom configuration for the plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
    <!-- below specify oauth2 to be false, as it's true by default -->
    <configuration>
      <oauth2>false</oauth2>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```